# What are examples of inversely (negatively) correlated stock prices in economics?

Tags: microeconomics, stock-market, price

I’m looking for example of two goods/wealth that demonstrate inverse/negative correlation. For example if price of `A` rises then price of `B` falls. May be it is oil or gold prices along with some other wealth. Or may be some share prices (stocks) of some two companies. I can’t find example of such negatively correlated prices data.

Comment: Among different QA communities (Quora, Reddit) StackExchange is the most aggressive one.

Comment: You can find countless correlation by google or simply find anything that fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U.S. equity market returns and U.S. Treasuries returns exhibit strong negative correlation (roughly -35%) over all time frequencies for sufficiently long time horizons.  We attribute this inverse correlation to the fact that Treasuries are "safe-haven" assets, while equities increase in price as risk premiums decline.

Your question mentions price data.  Your correlations will improve if you look at log-prices or returns.

There are many other examples of positive and negative correlations in finance, though many can prove ephemeral: utilities stocks and interest rates, long interest rates and life insurers, gold miners and gold prices, airlines and oil prices, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Google? By copying a part of your question into Google I was able to find several examples. The best one may be this site which lists 20 positively and negatively correlated stocks for any stock you pick: 
http://www.market-topology.com/correlation/